# R: robust package -- lmRob how to find the psi function used in the calculations

Tags: r, robust

I am using lmRob.

```
require(robust)
stack.rob.int <- lmRob(Loss ~.*., data = stack.dat)
```

Fine but, I was wondering how I could obtain the psi-function that is used by the lmRob function in the actual fitting. Thanks in advance for any help!

If I were to use the lmrob function in robustbase, is it possible to change the psi function to subtract it by a constant. I am trying to implement the bootstrap as per Lahiri (Annals of Statistics, 1992) where the way to still keep the bootstrap valid is mentioned to be to replace the psi() with  the originalpsi() minus the mean ot the residuals while fitting the bootstrap for the robust linear model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is no way to access the `psi` function directly for `robust::lmRob()`.

Simply put, `lmRob()` calls [`lmRob.fit()` (or `lmRob.wfit()` if you supply weights)](https://github.com/cran/robust/blob/0adc995035a5c51f0b58cc92c510e8461363dd69/R/lmRob.q#L72-L77) which subsequently calls [`lmRob.fit.compute()`](https://github.com/cran/robust/blob/0adc995035a5c51f0b58cc92c510e8461363dd69/R/lmRob.fit.q#L7-L8) that then sets [initial values for a Fortran version](https://github.com/cran/robust/blob/0adc995035a5c51f0b58cc92c510e8461363dd69/R/lmRob.fit.compute.q#L172-L188) depending on the [`lmRob.control()` set to either `"bisquare"` or `"optimal"`](https://github.com/cran/robust/blob/0adc995035a5c51f0b58cc92c510e8461363dd69/R/lmRob.control.q#L18-L20).

As a result of the above discussion, if you need access to the psi functions, you may wish to use [`robustbase`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=robustbase) as it has easy access to many [psi functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/vignettes/psi_functions.pdf) (c.f. the [biweights](https://github.com/cran/robustbase/blob/7f9e65c39d26b904b2eca7d5d7570548a14590e4/R/biweight-funs.R))

#### Edit 1

Regarding:

> psi function evaluated at the residuals in lmRob

No. The details of what is available after running `lmRob` is available in the `lmRob.object`. The documentation is accessible via `?lmRob.object`. Regarding residuals, the following *are* available in the `lmRob` object.

- `residuals`: the residual vector corresponding to the estimates returned in `coefficients`.
- `T.residuals`: the residual vector corresponding to the estimates returned in `T.coefficients`.
- `M.weights`: the robust estimate weights corresponding to the final MM-estimates in `coefficients`, if applies.
- `T.M.weights`: the robust estimate weights corresponding to the initial S-estimates in `T.coefficients`, if applies.

Regarding

> what does "optimal" do in lmRob?

Optimal refers to the following psi function:

```
sign(x)*(- (phi'(|x|) + c) / (phi(|x|) )
```

For other traditional psi functions, you may wish to look at [`robustbase`'s vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/vignettes/psi_functions.pdf)
or a robust textbook.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to access the psi function evaluated at the residuals in lmRob? That is really what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also, what does "optimal" do in lmRob? The help referes to Page 58-59 of Chapter 2 in Robust.pdf but I have no idea where to get Robust.pdf from. Thanks again!

Comment: See above. @user3236841